# Assessing Variation in Proportions and Describing Proportion Variability for Categorical Data Analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, inference, proportion, variability

I am working with a dataset that consists of three different factory groups, each producing laptops and receiving feedback reports on their products. Each observation includes the total number of laptops made, the number of feedback reports received, and the count of negative feedback. My objective is to analyze the variation in the proportion of negative feedback among these factory groups and describe the variability of these proportions.

For instance, here is a snippet of my dataset:

```
Factory Group  Subject  Laptops Made  Feedback_Reports_Received  Negative Feedback
A              X1       1548          10                        4
A              X2       5624          5                         3
A              X3       5214          9                         5
...
C              X30      8362          6                         5
```

To begin with, I am planning to perform a chi-square test for independence for each factory group to determine if the proportion of negative feedback is the same across groups. However, I'm uncertain about the best way to describe the variability of the proportions.

One approach I have considered is calculating the coefficient of variation (CV) for the mean of the proportion of negative feedback. For instance, considering the 'Factory Group A' in the dataset above, I calculate the percentage of negative feedback for each observation, resulting in proportions ranging from 0.25 to 1.00. Then, by computing the CV of these proportions, I aim to describe the variability of the proportion of negative feedback within 'Factory Group A.'

My question is: Is it appropriate to use the coefficient of variation (CV) to quantify the variability of proportions in this context? If not, are there alternative or better approaches to consider when analyzing and describing the variability of proportions, similar to the coefficient of variation used for continuous variables?

Additionally, I would appreciate if you could reference or refer me to some articles or papers on the matter thank you so much guys indeed.

Thank you in advance!

here is my full dataset:
python users
import pandas as pd

```
data = {
    'Factory Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Subject': ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12', 'X13', 'X14', 'X15', 'X16', 'X17', 'X18', 'X19', 'X20', 'X21', 'X22', 'X23', 'X24', 'X25', 'X26', 'X27', 'X28', 'X29', 'X30'],
    'Laptops Made': [1548, 5624, 5214, 521, 5245, 214, 2214, 521, 150, 521, 189, 619, 1050, 1480, 1910, 2340, 2770, 3200, 3631, 4061, 4491, 4921, 5351, 5781, 6212, 6642, 7072, 7502, 7932, 8362],
    'Feedback_Reports_Received': [10, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 12, 20, 19, 3, 14, 14, 15, 16, 16, 8, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 3, 7, 21, 6],
    'Negative Feedback': [4, 3, 5, 8, 7, 3, 3, 19, 6, 2, 9, 1, 13, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 1, 9, 7, 2, 2, 1, 7, 10, 5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

R users

```
df <- data.frame(
  'Factory Group' = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  'Subject' = c('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12', 'X13', 'X14', 'X15', 'X16', 'X17', 'X18', 'X19', 'X20', 'X21',
```